# What is the most efficient way of finding the first element of the ith row when A[i,j]=j*(A[i-1,j+1]-A[i-1,j])?

Tags: algorithm, math, bernoulli-numbers

When the first row is 1, 1/2 , 1/3 ....
Here's an image to support the question.
[image: image for better description.]

Does there exist a more efficient approach than the naive O(n^2) approach?

I came across this when studying Bernoulli numbers and then consequently on reaching "Akiyama–Tanigawa algorithm".

One of the ways could be simple precomputing the results and storing them in a table. Since Bernoulli numbers grow very quickly, for most practical purposes we wouldn't need Bernoulli numbers for much larger n. Consider Bernoulli(400)- its around -(10^550).

But looking at it only algorithmically, is there a better approach than the O(n^2) one?

Comment: I would suggest to upload your figure image to SO.

Comment: Click on the picture icon while editing (on the top, right from {}). If the image appears to big for you, see also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165795/how-to-make-pictures-smaller)

Comment: Looks as if it takes significant mathematical effort to find and prove faster methods of computation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernouilli_numbers#Efficient_computation_of_Bernoulli_numbers

Comment: Hmm...so you mean to say that there's no more efficient way of solving this without applying the kind of mathematics that they have applied?

Comment: @NikharAgrawal: I mean to say that if there was an easy way of doing it as efficiently as those papers do it, then finding a harder way to do it that efficiently would not have been worth publishing :-)

Comment: hmm...True enough I guess. :)

Comment: Assuming you're using a 1-based index.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic - theoretical cs or math (as the tags would suggest)

Answer (score 4):

The first elements form the sequence of [Bernoulli numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html).  The numerators and denominators for the Bernoulli numbers are found using the [A027641](http://oeis.org/A027641) sequence and [A027642](http://oeis.org/A027642) sequence, respectively.  Both of those sequences have closed-form sums on their respective pages that can be used to compute their terms.